# Open source html5 document viewer for mobile apps

Tags: html, pdf, documentviewer, document-conversion

I am building mobile app for Android and iOS platforms using Phonegap. I want to use a **html5 document viewer** to display **pdf's, ppt's** and all in the mobile app.
I saw Crocodoc. Its good, but i need to something open source which i can tinker with. 
Can you please suggest if currently there are any open source solutions to display documents in the mobile app ??